# Why not enter catch

Tags: javascript

Forgive me for my poor English and use translation software to describe the problem.

In project, resolve and reject appear at the same time. Why not enter catch,
This is a code snippet

```
function pro() {
    console.log(5)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(1);
        resolve();
        console.log(2);
        reject('error');
    })
}
pro().then(() => {
    console.log(3);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
console.log(4)
```

Is it because `resolve()` changes the state from 'pending' of promise to 'resolved'?

Comment: "*Is it because resolve() changes the state from 'pending' of promise to 'resolved'?*" yes - promises cannot move to more than one state. Once they are no longer pending, that's their final state.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it because resolve() changes the state from 'pending' of promise to 'resolved'?

Yes. Once the promise is settled (resolved or rejected), further calls to `resolve()` or `reject()` do nothing.